# Convert Numpy Array to Video(mp4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, video

I have a video(mp4) that I read into a Numpy Array and edit. Now I want to convert the array back to a video

I already tried to use VideoWriter but the created mp4 was always corrupt

```
frame_array = []
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while cap.isOpened():
      ret, image_np = cap.read()
      if ret == True:
          image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
          image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
          boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
          scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
          classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
          num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
          (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
              [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
              feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
          vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
              image_np,
              np.squeeze(boxes),
              np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
              np.squeeze(scores),
              category_index,
              use_normalized_coordinates=True,
              line_thickness=8)
          i=i+1
          frame_array.append(image_np)
          cv2.imwrite('pictures/'+ str(i) + '.jpg',image_np)
      else:
          break
print("Everything detected")
out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 30, (640, 480))
for i in frame_array:
    out.write(i)
out.release()
```

The created mp4 was always corrupt and couldnt be opened. Every saved Picture with `cv2.imwrite` is okay and viewable

Comment: Okay i solved it. I had to change this line ```out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 30, (640, 480))``` to 
```out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 30, (1920, 1080))```

Comment: First, check the file size. Is it large (like a video file) or tiny? If it's large, you just have an encoding issue or something---try using a more basic container/encoding combo, e.g. `.avi` and `'MJPG'`. If the file size is tiny, then you have a different problem, most likely that the image size is different from the writer frame size that you specified.

Comment: Ah glad you got it solved. Don't just add that as a comment though, either delete the question if you feel its unlikely to help anyone else, otherwise write your own answer to your question!